# how to interconnect custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta

I'd like to make a site about choirs, composers, conductors and singers. And so far I decided that I need to make a custom post type for "piece" -- any piece can be associated with choir[s], composer, conductor and singer[s].

I could do this with taxonomies (tags), assigned to every "piece". But I need to be able to write about conductors, too. So, I need to create another post type?

So, now I have "piece", "conductor", "composer" post types. And I can use [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to interconnect them.

But in some cases conductor may act as a soloist -- and it seems that I could create "person" type, but anyway I can not say that "piece"<--(conductor)-->"person" and "piece"<--(soloist)-->"the_same_person" with posts2posts.

Actually I think that I need these post types (should I use tags for some?): piece, conductor, composer, soloist, collection (CD or live performance) and I need for some of them to have custom fields (creation year, publication year etc) -- hope this can be done too by other means. I guess I could add custom fields to piece and put "conductor_id" here.

Do I overcomplicate things?

How this could be done?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Thanks, scribu; I was wrong: it looks like posts2posts is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to define two post types: 'piece' and 'person' and a connection field 'role'.

See https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Connection-information

Comment: Very interesting and attractive, i need to try this. Thanks! Anyway, I guess I need to create post type "collection", too.. May be some other.

Comment: yes, i know how stackexchange works.) I need some reputation to vote, anyway. And now I need to draw with pencil more .)

Comment: Yes, it seems I need exactly that. Sorry, I've said that p2p could not do this .) So, I will try, thank you!

Comment: I got fatal error on activating it.

Comment: @Rajiv: With what error message?